# JavaScript code for getting the selected value from a combo box

Tags: javascript, combobox

Can any one give me a sample code that gets the selected value from an existing combo box?

I have this code but its not doing anything:

```
function check () 
{
    var e = document.getElementById("ticket_category_clone");
    var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    alert(str);

    if (str==="Hardware")
    {
        SPICEWORKS.utils.addStyle('#ticket_c_hardware_clone{display: none !important;}');
    }       
}

SPICEWORKS.app.helpdesk.ready(check);​
```

heres a [img](http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/9250/efrefr.png) of the code

and the code

```
<select id="ticket_category_clone" name="ticket[category]" hdpp="ticket_category">
<option value=""></option><option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
<option value="Software">Software</option>
<option value="Rede" selected="selected">Rede</option>
<option value="Pedidos">Pedidos</option>
<option value="Formação/Dúvida">Formação/Dúvida</option>
<option value="Outro">Outro</option><option value="#edit_categories#">Edit Categories...</option></select>
```

what i want its find a way to get the selected value fo that combobox

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is an unnecessary hashtag; change the code to this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ticket_category_clone").value;
```

Comment: @user181891 thats why is not getting the value, add ".value" after 
parenthesis just like that:

var e = document.getElementById("ticket_category_clone").value;

Answer (score 4):

I use this

```
var e = document.getElementById('ticket_category_clone').value;
```

Notice that you don't need the '#' character in javascript.

```
    function check () {

    var str = document.getElementById('ticket_category_clone').value;

      if (str==="Hardware")
      {
        SPICEWORKS.utils.addStyle('#ticket_c_hardware_clone{display: none !important;}');
      }

    }

SPICEWORKS.app.helpdesk.ready(check);​
```

Comment: i dont need the # even if it is on the id of the combobox?

Comment: Not when you are using vanilla javascript, it's only required when you use a framework ( that requires it ) , like jQuery

Comment: @user181891 Have you found the answer you were looking for? If not, edit your question with some html containing the combobox. If yes, plz check the best answer as sollution.

Comment: My code should work: check out this samle: http://jsfiddle.net/em6rf/ just click the run button on top. I've updated my code with you example and the working javascript.

Answer (score 2):

It probably is the # sign like tho others have mentioned because this appears to work just fine.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

    <select id="#ticket_category_clone">
  <option value="hw">Hardware</option>
  <option>fsdf</option>
  <option>sfsd</option>
  <option>sdfs</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function check() {
        var e = document.getElementById("#ticket_category_clone");
        var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

        alert(str);
        if (str === "Hardware") { 
            alert('Hi'); 
        }


    })();
</script>
</body>
```