# Is there something like ".checked for a dropdown list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I am making a website for my university project(using HTML-CSS-javascript).
I made a dropdown list and I want a function to do something different with 
every choice from the drop-down list

For example when they pick "2 swords" an alert to say "sword 2"

thank you for your time :)

html code:

```
<select name="swordlist">
  <option id="one">1 sword</option>
  <option id="two">2 swords</option>
  <option id="three">3 swords</option>
</select>
```

javascript code:

```
var swordlist1 = document.getElementById('one').checked;
var swordlist2 = document.getElementById('two').checked;
var swordlist3 = document.getElementById('three').checked;

if(swordlist1 == true) {
  alert("sword 1");
} else if(swordlist2 == true) {
  alert("sword 2");
} else if(swordlist3 == true) {
  alert("sword 3");
}
```

and a button to call the function after you pick something from the drop-down list (if you know a way to call the function without any button just for selecting that would be very nice):

```
<input type="button" onclick="WholeCost();" id="test" value="test">
```

Comment: select's value will give you the checked option's value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript code for getting the selected value from a combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007774/javascript-code-for-getting-the-selected-value-from-a-combo-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `selected` property to check if a select option is selected.

`Checked` is for radio buttons and checkboxes.

But if you want to check which element is selected of a select element you don't need to check each option, you can check the `value` property of the html select element.

You can also add the property `value` to your option elements, it is usually useful to have an internal value that it is easy to deal with and then show another value/text to the user.

You can also call your method `WholeCost` attaching it to `onchange` event of the select html element. Your method will be called every time the select changes. So no need to add an html button that needs to be clicked.

Like this:

```js
function WholeCost(e) {
  // Get selected option without checking one by one
  console.log(e.value);

  // Instead of checked, use selected for select elements
  var swordlist1 = document.getElementById('one').selected;
  var swordlist2 = document.getElementById('two').selected;
  var swordlist3 = document.getElementById('three').selected;

  if(swordlist1 == true) {
    alert("sword 1");
    
  } else if(swordlist2 == true) {
    alert("sword 2");
    
  } else if(swordlist3 == true) {
    alert("sword 3");
  }  
}
```

```html
<!-- call your method WholeCost when selected option changes -->
<select name="swordlist" onchange="WholeCost(this)">
  <!-- each option has the property value -->
  <option value="one" id="one">1 sword</option>
  <option value="two" id="two">2 swords</option>
  <option value="three" id="three">3 swords</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select's value will give you the checked option's value. So, you need to add value to options.
Previous answer is also correct but this is much easier. Especially if you have a long select element

```
<select name="swordlist" id="swordlist">
    <option value="one">1 sword</option>
    <option value="two">2 swords</option>
    <option value="three">3 swords</option>
</select>

<script>
function WholeCost(){
    var selectedSword = document.getElementById('swordlist').value;
    alert(selectedSword)
}
</script>
```